# How to limit number of simultaneous connections to an SFTP server with Open SSH

Tags: ssh, openssh, sftp

I used Open SSH to set up an SFTP server on a Windows instance of AWS, this server will be used by two parties A and B, B will put some files in the SFTP server, and A will retrieve them, I need to limit the number of simultaneous connections in the SFTP to 1 so that A will not retrieve files at the same time that B is putting them in the SFTP (there is a risk of retrieving an incomplete file). So limiting the number of simultaneous connections to the SFTP server to 1 so that when each party try to connect to the server and receive a maximum connection error, it would wait for some time before reconnecting (each party is essentially a computer program).

The problem is when I change the `MaxSessions` and `MaxStartups` in `sshd_config` to 1, it still allows me to run 2 or more connections at the same time.

Here is the sshd_config of the server :

```
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
SyslogFacility LOCAL0
LogLevel VERBOSE

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
MaxSessions 1

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
MaxStartups 1
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: Can the actual programs A and B be altered, or is that outside of your control?

Comment: @user1686 I have control over program A (the one that retrieve those files), but not on B (the one that put the files)

Comment: Well, AFAIK `MaxSessions` is sessions per network connection, `MaxStartups` applies to concurrent *unauthenticated* connections. No wonder they don't work the way you want.

Comment: I guess one way to do this server-side is to create a wrapper over `sftp-server.exe`. The wrapper should try to obtain some sort of exclusive lock and (if managed to get the lock) exec to the real `sftp-server`. In Linux I would use `flock` for this.